# Is it possible to use ajax request to controller method without responseBody annotation to return recompiled jsp?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to rerender part of my page without page reloading.

I am going to use ajax request to accomplish it.

All examples I found uses `@ResponseBody` annotation and on client javaScript handle xml or json.

My cause - get htm fragment and replace part of my page

structure:

**bigJsp.jsp**

```
...
incude small.jsp
...
```

I want to get rerendered `small.jsp` and replace it on my page without page reloading.

I cannot found example of this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try do following:

1) replace your include small.jsp to some div.

```
<div id="smallContent"></div>
```

2) create controller method that creates a proper view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "small", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testSmall(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("small_message", new Date().toString());
        return "small";
    }
```

3) create your small view (small.jsp):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<div style="background: red">
My message: ${small_message}
</div>
```

4) use ajax to get html content for your div:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function reloadSmall() {
            $.get("/small", function(response) {
                $("#smallContent").html(response);
            });
        }
    </script>
<div id="smallContent" style="background: green"></div>
<button onclick="reloadSmall()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller method return *ModelAndView*, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/small", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView smallJSP()  {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("small");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

the controller will search for the view with the name small, on the default location and with the default suffix (depending on your configuration e.g. `/WEB-INF/views/small.jsp`). Than you should simply call the method with an appropriate ajax call, e.g. via jquery

```
     $.ajax({
            url:"/small",
            dataType: "html",
            type: "GET",          
            success: function (msg) {
               $(".responseDiv").html(msg);// place your response to some div
            }
        });
```

Comment: will msg a compiled html?

Comment: yes, its the variable where the response is set, added an edit